# ‘be mistaken’ or ‘have mistaken’

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice

I didn’t doubt what he said. I didn’t expect him to be mistaken.

Why not use ‘have mistaken’ instead of ‘be mistaken’?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this sentence

> I didn’t expect him to be mistaken.

the word **mistaken** is an adjective describing "him".

But in this sentence

> I didn’t expect him to have mistaken.

the sentence is using **mistaken** as a verb, and is incomplete.

It could be

> I didn’t expect him to have mistaken a bird for a plane.

Comment: Must the second add something after mistaken?

Comment: I added an **object** in the third example, the thing about which he was mistaken.

Comment: @Y.zeng Because of how we formulate past tenses, it would only be grammatical without something else added if it were *to have **been** mistaken*.